# Display button when hovering over image (rails image_tag)

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, imagemagick, paperclip

here's what I'm trying to do: display images from my db and display an overlay with a download button (linked to a file's url) on top of the image when you hover your mouse over it.
see illustration here :http://cl.ly/image/2T200Z451K0v

I'm using rails and paperclip.
Here's basically what I have in my view:

```
<%= image_tag pin.image(:medium) %>
<%= link_to "download", pin.download_link, class: "btn btn-large btn-primary"%>
```

which displays the image and the download button below.

I've tried many things, I've managed to make the button appears only when I hover over the image but the button always stays below the image. I tried using position:relative but I guess it would work if the image was a div and the button was inside that div and I don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

It's easy enough to do this with HTML and CSS. Here's an example:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Hwfnz

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<style media="all">
div {width: 300px; height: 240px;}

a {display: table; width: 300px; height: 240px; vertical-align: middle; text-align: center; position: relative;}

span {display: none;}

a:hover span {width: 300px; height: 240px; line-height: 240px; position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0; display: block; text-align: center; background: rgba(67,81,96,0.7); }

span b {font-size: 1.5em; font-weight: normal; padding: 8px 12px; border-radius: 5px; background: #6bbe70; color: #fff; font-family: sans-serif;}

a:hover span b:hover {background: #000;}

img {background: #e7e7e7; border: none; vertical-align: bottom;}
</style>

</head>
<body>

<div>
    <a href=""><img src="http://pageaffairs.com/sp/so-16390475.jpg" width="300" height="240"> <span><b>download</b></span></a>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: the thing is, I'm in a html.erb file and I'm not using the <a href=""> and <img src=""> html tags, I'm using ruby code <%= image_tag %> and <%= link_to %> to load each image and download link from the db.

Comment: Is this a download button that will appear in a web page? If so, you will need to use HTML elements. Whatever you use on the backend, what's important is the code that's served up to the browser. What is your actual, generated HTML?

Comment: Yes, it's a download button that will appear in a web page, so you're right, the generated HTML will have <a> and <img> tag that will look something similar as what you wrote. But I'm trying to figure out how to generate this in my view in my rails app using <%=link_to%> and <%=image_tag%>. I guess I should try the <a> tag instead of  <%=link_to%>.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I finally did, following ralph's suggestion
html:

```
<div class="pin_image">
  <a href=<%= pin.download_link %>>
    <%= image_tag pin.image(:medium) %>
  <span><b>download</b></span>
  </a> 
</div>
```

css:

```
.pin_image {

a {
    display: table; 
    vertical-align: middle; 
    text-align: center; 
    position: relative;
}

span {
    display: none;
}

a:hover {
    span {
    display: block; 
    position: absolute;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center; 
    top:45%;
    width: 100%;
    }
}

span b {
    padding: 10px 20px;
    font-size: 22px;
    text-shadow: none;
    font-weight: normal;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    background:#2DC76E;
    color: white;   
}

a:hover span b:hover {
    background: #25A65B;
}
}
```